# How to distinguish between classes with the same unique identifier in a class diagram?

Tags: class-diagram

Can the primary key inbox_id in UserInbox be a foreign key for EmployerInformation and UserInformation?

Context:

Users and employers can send feedback to an administrator's inbox. This feedback will be stored in the table UserInbox. (image shown below) 
[image]

Issue:

Both UserInformation and EmployerInformation have record_id as a unique identifier- I'm not sure if I can use the identifier (message_id) to connect UserInformation and EmployerInformation to UserInbox as it is hard to distinguish between the two record_ids.

Comment: Why is the feedback *sent* by a user stored in his *inbox* in the first place? Surely it should be in his *outbox*, with a user/mailbox ID of who/where it was sent to? `inbox_id` looks like a *message* ID, not an attribute of a user. None of this makes much sense.

Comment: Hi EJP. Thanks for the heads. I have updated the class diagram. Should message_id act as a foreign key for UserInformation and EmployerInformation? I want to be able to know from whom any incoming messages to the admin inbox are arriving from.

Comment: A `message_id` doesn't identify a user or employer. It identifies a message. Surely somewhere you have a `User` table, with `user_id`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to make `inbox_id` as foreign key in `UserInfomation` and `EmployerInformation`, because one user may have numbers of feedbacks, then user information will be duplicated many times.

One approach to this problem is using idea of **inheritance**, meaning that both `UserInformation` and `EmployerInformation` inherit from `User` table, and `User` table keeps common information of `UserInformation` and `EmployerInformation` like `record_id` and `img_id`. `UserInbox` table will then keep `record_id` as a foreign key.

```
UserInformation ------ User ----- EmployerInformation
                        |
                     UserInbox
```

Comment: In class diagram, basically `UserInbox`, `UserInformation` and `EmployerInformation` will have `record_id` as foreign key from `User`. To select feedbacks from a user, you need to join `User` with `UserInbox`; To select user information, you need to join `User` with `UserInformation`. Join is expensive, so you can duplicate some fields depending on your application.